# Calculating unsigned number from binary numbers, using arrays and functions

Tags: c

I'm having a difficult time trying to calculate a number through an array that I have that contains only 0's and 1's. I have built a function that multiplies the exponent for each number but I'm having a bit of difficulty. 
The problem is that I run into a loop that calculates all of the exponents of 2 instead of running 3 times, so if I'm trying to calculate 0000000000000000000000000000111 (which supposed to run 3 times) I get 1,2,4,8,16,32,64...4194304... and all of that 3 times.

My code is:

```
for(int i = 31; i > 0; i--){
    if(EndArray[i] == 1){
        for(x = 0; x < 30 ; x++){
            UnsignedArray[30-x] = ExpoFunction(x);
        }
    }
}
```

ExpoFunction is:

```
int ExpoFunction(int x){
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++){
        result *= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

`EndArray` is an array that contains 32 numbers of 0's and 1's. example: 0000000000000000000000000000111 which supposed to be 7.
At the end of this, I want to put everything in a new array which called `UnsignedArray` and then to sum all of `UnsignedArray`'s numbers together.

Any ideas whats wrong or a better way?

Comment: I think you're over-complicating this.  For instance, the entire body of `ExpoFunction` can be replaced by `return 1 << x;`  It's a builtin C operator.  You don't need a function for it.  Just make sure you don't overflow.

Comment: Also,  your for loop's end conditions don't look right. For instance, you are missing `EndArray[0]` and `UnsignedArray[0]`

Comment: You run your `for(x` loop every time you have a `1` in `EndArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to store all exponents in `UnsignedArray`, then sum all value in this array to have the decimal number, right ? If i am not wrong, your `for` loop should change to:

```
   for(int i = 30; i >= 0; i--){ // should run from 30 to 0, not from 31 to 1
        if(EndArray[i] == 1){
            // just store one time, not using for loop of x as you did in your code.
            UnsignedArray[30-i] = ExpoFunction(30-i);
            printf("%d\n", UnsignedArray[30-i]); // if you want to test the value.
        } 
    }
```

The main function for testing:

```
int main()
{
    int EndArray[31] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1};
    unsigned int UnsignedArray[31] = {0};
    for(int i = 30; i >= 0; i--){
        if(EndArray[i] == 1){
            UnsignedArray[30-i] = ExpoFunction(30-i);
            printf("%u\n", UnsignedArray[30-i]);
        } 
    }

    unsigned int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        sum += UnsignedArray[i];
    }

    printf("decimal: %u", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
1
2                                                                                                                       
4                                                                                                                       
decimal: 7
```

Comment: Why are you calling `ExpoFunction`?  It's just a left shift.  Didn't you see my comment?

Comment: I agree that we can use left shift 1<< (30-i) but my answer does not focus on how he calculates the exponent. Because it’s not the problem make result get failed.

Comment: I remain his function because it’s not false. Anw, thank for your remind. :))